# Why am I getting repeated responses from api call? I am sending an api request and get back same responses from the data in retrofit android

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I am using the pexels library to fetch the images using retrofit api in android.

I am getting same images in every api call like retrofit is catching images and showing those images only.

So, can anyone guide me how to solve this problem

Comment: Check your Interceptor... Default cache null...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.